# Can Library folder on iMac be moved to iCloud Drive?

Tags: macos, icloud, library

My disk in my iMac, High Sierra is about full. The biggest culprit by far is the /User/myname/Library folder which is taking up 96 GB. Since I have over 100 GB of icloud storage could I move the Library folder to the icloud drive and create a link? How do I do that so iMac still can access the Library.  If this is a stupid question I apologize.

OmniDiskSweeper says ~/Library is 73.9 GB. Don't know where the other 22 GB went.  From OmniDisksweeper the storage hogs in ~/Library are:

1. Application Support - 20 GB with MobileSync being the major player
2. Containers - 18 GB  with com.apple.mail being the major player
3. Mobile Documents - 18 GB with com~apple~CloudDocs being the hog.

Comment: actually ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents contains iCloud documents too.. So accidental recursion ? ;p

Comment: Before trying that, find why that folder is so large. iPhone backups no longer needed? Start with `cd ~/Library ; du -sm * | sort -n` in a Terminal window.

Comment: I just did this but I don't know if numbers are GB, MB or some other unit.  The memory hogs using this method appear to be: Application Support, Mobile Documents, and Containers.  Does this tell you anything?

Comment: The numbers output by `du -sm` are in MB.

Comment: @lhf  Thank you. i updated my question with the results from OmniDiskSweeper..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Firstly, relying on an internet connection to access preferences, caches, and other system/user 'working' files is likely to be problematic. As mentioned in the comments, iCloud is handled locally by a folder in the user Library, so having this itself in iCloud might be confusingly recursive.

It's worth checking whether all of that 96 Gb is necessary: it may include iPhone or iPad backups, which are frequent culprits for taking up space. Use an app like OmniDiskSweeper to search the library, sorted by size. That will show you what is taking the space, and you can then make a decision about whether it can be moved or deleted.

Answer (score -5):

The only way to do this would be to disable SIP first.

And then when you reboot into normal mode, you'll find a lot of things broken.

But there are probably things in ~/Library that can be deleted.  How to know what's safe to delete is too complicated to put here.

Comment: Nope, the OP is asking about **HIS** users folder which is not SIP protected. You are referring to the root "/Library" folder I believe...

Comment: No, I am not.  There are many subdirectories of ~/Library that not only are SIP-protected, but the user can't even look in them.  Whenever I try to use `find` to look for something, I have to redirect to a file, because I can't find the answer in all the "permission denied" messages.  And if I do `sudo chown -R byname:staff /Users/myname/` I get the same monstrous list of "permission denied."